# Getting "Unknown command" when using "lftp -e"

Tags: linux, bash, ftp, automation, lftp

I'm working on a bash script to automate FTP sessions, so I can run the same commands on multiple servers automatically)

```
lftp -u username,password ip_address -e **FILE_WITH_COMMANDS**
```

So the problem is that I somehow can't use a file with `-f` because I get an error like this:

> Unknown command `commands'.

Does anybody know how to get around this problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is `commands`? Is it the name of the `**FILE_WITH_COMMANDS**`?

Answer (score 1):

To execute commands loaded from a file, use the `-f` switch:

> -f            execute commands from the file and exit

---

The `-e` switch is for executing a command specified on the command-line:

> -e             execute the command

So when you use `-e commands`, the `lftp` interprets it as a request to run the `commands` command. And there's no `commands` command, hence the error.

---

See also https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html